# How can I subscribe to changes in a redux store within an actions file

Tags: redux, react-redux

I have the following code

```
const reduxStore =  require('redux/store');
console.log(typeof reduxStore.subscribe);
```

If I run that in a redux actions file my typeof is undefined. 
If I run it in a vanilla js my typeof is function.

Now maybe doing this seems counterintuitive but I have a pattern where I have a shared actions file, that is to say the actions defined in this file can be used in two different reducers.

However some of these actions while shared between reducers (reducer1, reducer2) must cause actions to run that are individual to the particular store domain.

So dependant on what happens when reducer1.acceptGeoCode runs in the part of the application using reducer2 then reducer2.geoCodeSuccess should be run or reducer2.geoCodeFailed

it seems easiest to me to subscribe to changes in my reducer2 actions js, and then on the changes dispatch the local action I should use.

So that is why I want to use reduxStore.subscribe within an actions file. How do I do that, or failing that what is the proper way to do what I want to do which I feel must be doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have reducer 2 be aware of how reducer1 handled an action, is that right?

The way to do that is by *composing* reducers (as opposed to combining them). See this in action here: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40749773/composing-higher-order-reducers-in-redux)

A couple of other points that might help you on your way:

- Reducers should be *pure*. This means we don't do ajax calls (or other side effects) from inside a reducer. That is the domain of actions (ex: redux-thunk) and middlewares.
- In the majority of applications, there should really only be one store. So, if you have a pattern where you have one store subscribing to another, then you should probably refactor your code to have just one store. Just to be clear, you can have several reducers combined (or composed) together in a single store - that's how Redux is designed to work.